# Distribute an cylinder to a hexagonal grid with python

Tags: python

I have create mesh cylinder with distribution hexagone, i use method from modifier array, I created a cylinder dimension x * y * z or z is the depth of this mesh

Are you a script to draw this distribution
exemple
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do the trick (**EDITED** to also generate ellipses):

```
import bpy

rowLen = 10 # Number of cylinders per row (along X)
colLen = 10 # Number of cylinders per column (along Y)
xDist  = 4  # Distance between cylinders in X
yDist  = 2  # Distance between cylinders in Y

ellipseRatio = 1.5 # X/Y ratio (cylinder xScale)

for i in range( rowLen ):
    y = i * yDist
    for j in range( colLen ):
        x = j * xDist if i % 2 == 0 else (j + 0.5) * xDist 

        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(
            vertices      = 24,
            radius        = 1,
            depth         = 5,
            end_fill_type = 'NGON', 
            location      = (x, y, 0)
        )

        o = bpy.context.object # Newly created cylinder is the active (context) object
        o.scale.x = ellipseRatio
```

Change the xDist and yDist to control the distance between cylinders in X and Y.
Change the rowLen and colLen to change the number of cylinders in each row or column.

The number of vertices, radius, depth and end fill type are specified within the `bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add` operator as parameters.

[image]

Comment: good work Tlousky, but cylinder base is an ellipse that is not a circle, how to change the x and y dimension of the cylinder?

Comment: @saded - updated the answer, creates ellipses as well now